# How can I remove quotes from serilaized string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to produce a JSON document, that will be parsed by a SSI mechanism on a device. The document will actually be a json serialized dictionary. For the sake of simplicity, let's say, that it should look like this:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string,object> 
    { 
    ["A"]=new {x = "<!-- ?A.x -->"},
    ["B"]=new {x = "<!-- ?B.x -->"} 
    };

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x).Dump();
```

Which produces in LinqPad:

```
{"A":{"x":"<!-- ?A.x -->"},"B":{"x":"<!-- ?B.x -->"}}
```

But actually those "x" fields are numbers, and when fetched from the device, they will contain numbers. So I would need to serialize this dictionary without quotes around a field value that is string on C# side:

```
{"A":{"x":<!-- ?A.x -->},"B":{"x":<!-- ?B.x -->}}
```

How can I force Newtonsoft Json.NET serializer not to add quotes to the value of specific fields (not all) during serialization?

Thank you.

Comment: `{"A":{"x":<!-- ?A.x -->},"B":{"x":<!-- ?B.x -->}}` would be invalid Json though? You can't expect a json serializer to produce invalid json. Why don't you just build the string (because this is a string and isn't Json) yourself?

Comment: To prove my point put `{"A":{"x":<!-- ?A.x -->},"B":{"x":<!-- ?B.x -->}}` into [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/).. `Error: Parse error on line 3:{ "A": {  "x": },"B":{`

Comment: @Liam: Of course it is not valid JSON in this form. I never said that. But will be valid after the device is processing it, by replacing the <!-- --> sections with a numbers. I know that this is kind of woring around the normal way of working.

Comment: Your missing my point, you can't expect a json serializer to produce invalid json. If you want this format you need to produce it yourself, not use Json.Net

Comment: I absolutelly got your point. But as you can see, I can still achieve it. Why should I reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is by introducing new `JsonConverter` [(sample)](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm). To separate the functionality of "raw serialization", you could introduce new type that would just wrap a string value, eg.

```
public class RawJson
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public RawJson(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Then you just check for this type in converter's `CanConvert()` and in `WriteJson()` you can just write

```
writer.WriteRawValue(((RawJson)value).Value);
```

Comment: you gave me the path, but the solution is even simpler. Ok, my example was not good enough, as I am not using anonymous classes, but I have them declared. I accept your answer, but I am posting the final version below.

Answer (score 1):

And below is the actual solution, based on @kiziu's suggestion to use custom converter. But without custom type. As the converter can be added with the attribute to members too, and not only to classes or the converter itself, I can use it on the property I need. The above LinqPad scratch updated:

```
internal class RawJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(string);
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteRawValue((string)value);
        }
    }

class myClass 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(RawJsonConverter))]
    public string x;
}

void Main()
{
    var x = new Dictionary<string,object> 
        { 
        ["A"]=new myClass {x = "<!-- ?A.x -->"},
        ["B"]=new myClass {x = "<!-- ?B.x -->"} 
        };


    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x).Dump();
}
```

And the result is, as expected:

```
{"A":{"x":<!-- ?A.x -->},"B":{"x":<!-- ?B.x -->}}
```